# Get Instapaper to save blog comments with article

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, software-recommendation, instapaper

I recently bought the highly respected [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) app for my iPhone.

One thing I have noticed is that if I save an article from (most) blogs such as [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com), the comments to the article are not saved in the Instapaper version.

While in many cases the comments are mindless noise, and I can understand why Instapaper would strip them, there are some blogs where the comments are very much part of the conversation and I'd love to see them, formatted nicely, in the Instapaper output.

Does anyone know an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer, Instapaper deliberately doesn't copy comments.  One solution would be to copy all the text, and email it to your Instapaper email address (which can be found by logging in, then looking here http://www.instapaper.com/extras - 3rd item down.

Answer (score 2):

Instapaper uses various filters to figure out what to strip from the page and which content to keep ([Coding Horror configuration is here](http://www.instapaper.com/bodytext/edit/228)).

My only suggestion would to be to write a script which takes the content + comments, puts them into a new page wrapped in a div which has the class instapaper_body and saves that to Instapaper.

Comment: I didn't know about by domain configuration & `instapaper_*` classes, thanks for the link !

Concerning the "rewrite" of the page, it should be possible to make a bookmarklet to do just that. [Here's a tutorial on how to make one with jQuery](http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/) (which will make the task a lot easier, I think).

Comment: As of today the link with Coding Horror config is no longer working, but [this](http://blog.instapaper.com/post/730281947) gives a clue about these `instapaper_*` classes